# How can I use stepper for specific degree?

Tags: stepper

I use Arduino and I'm beginner. I use the code below, but I don't understand what `stepper.step(num)` and `STEPS` in `Stepper stepper(STEPS, 2,3,4,5)` are, and I want to use stepper for specific degree and I don't know what I can do. for example if I want to use stepper for 40 degree what are STEP and num?

```C++
#include <Stepper.h>

// change this to the number of steps on your motor
#define STEPS 100

// create an instance of the stepper class, specifying
// the number of steps of the motor and the pins it's
// attached to
Stepper stepper(STEPS, 2,3,4,5);

// the previous reading from the analog input
int previous = 0;

void setup()
{
  // set the speed of the motor to 30 RPMs
  stepper.setSpeed(100);
}

void loop()
{
  // get the sensor value
  //int val = analogRead(0);

  // move a number of steps equal to the change in the
  // sensor reading
  //stepper.step(val - previous);
  stepper.step(25);
  delay(1000000);
 // stepper.step(-5);


  // remember the previous value of the sensor
  //previous = val;
}
```

-----------------------------------------EDIT #2-----------------------------
my stepper is the first one in this link:
https://grahamwideman.wikispaces.com/file/view/28byj48_models_table.jpg/538898220/604x265/28byj48_models_table.jpg
( I think! )
and I don't know what it means?
------------------------------------------EDIT #3----------------------------
Thank you very much, I saw the link.

> Step Angle (8-Step sequence: Internal Motor alone): 5.625° (64 steps
>   per revolution)

and I run this code for 45deg :

```C++
#include <Stepper.h>

#define STEPS_PER_MOTOR_REVOLUTION 32   
#define STEPS_PER_OUTPUT_REVOLUTION 32 * 64  //2048  
Stepper small_stepper(STEPS_PER_MOTOR_REVOLUTION, 2, 3, 4, 5);

int  Steps2Take;

void setup()   
{

}

void loop()   /*----( LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY )----*/
{

  Steps2Take  =  STEPS_PER_OUTPUT_REVOLUTION / 8.11;          
  small_stepper.setSpeed(100);   
  small_stepper.step(Steps2Take);
  delay(10000);
}
```

because I understand each turn has 2048 steps, for example if I want to have 1/2 turn, I have to have num=1024 ( 2048/2). ok, So, for 45deg, it's 1/8 turn so I have to set num=2048/8. but for example for 33 deg what should I do? 
I thought num= 33*5.61 
so for 45deg I use num=45*5.61
you know we have a lot of floating point and I'm not sure we do it correct. right? I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stepper.step(num)`is used to rotate your motor 'num'-step. i.e. `num=25`, then calling `stepper.step` will cause your motor do 25-step.

STEPS is number of steps per revolution for your motor. It will be depending on the motor you used. For more information, you can check [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StepperOneStepAtATime).

You have to check for your motor stepper resolution. Most common motor stepper has 200 steps per revolution, which means 1 step is 360/200 = 1.8 degree. If you try `Stepper.step(1)`, your motor will rotate 1.8 degree.

So in your case, if you already found out the resolution of your motor stepper, just do a simple conversion task:

```
const float resolution  = xx.xx; // put your step resolution here
int step_degree(float desired_degree){
    return (desired_degree/resolution);}
```

This can be use by calling

```
stepper.step(step_degree(40)); //rotate 40 degree.
```

**--EDIT--**
You can check this [link](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/SmallSteppers), since it (perhaps) using same motor stepper (24BYJ48)

Based on 24BYJ48 [datasheet](https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi-7Lf4sa_QAhWKpY8KHWL1D7AQFggrMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsmart-elektronic.strefa.pl%2Fsilnik%2Fdatasheet.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGcovDwZtfT8XvQGshhTXc1g-o5Qw&sig2=F752FfDr8P0FzKlwsoRzTQ&bvm=bv.139138859,d.c2I), it has 5.625 degree resolution / 64 steps per revolution.

Comment: Do you mean 1 step is 360/200 = 1.8deg?

Comment: https://grahamwideman.wikispaces.com/file/view/28byj48_models_table.jpg/538898220/604x265/28byj48_models_table.jpg

Comment: I sent a link, the firs one is my stepper. but I don't know what they are. Would you please tell me what is my resolution?

Comment: I set 200 and I expect with num=1 I have to see 1.8 degree but it wasn't.

Comment: Instead of put in comment, it will be better if you put edit your question so others can quickly notice it :)

Comment: Thanks , I edit it, but I don't know what is the correct step